# Notice: Undefined variable: obj in

Tags: php, mysql, class, object

When i prepare the `$sql`, i got error "`Notice: Undefined variable: obj in..`"

**member.php**

```
<?php   
require_once('database.php');
$obj = new Database;
$obj->getConnection();
class Member{

private $username;
private $userpassword;

public function regist(){

if(isset($_POST['action'])&&$_POST['action']=='insert'){
try{

    $sql = "INSERT INTO userData(username,password)VALUES(:username,:password)";
    $stmh = $obj->prepare($sql);//the error occour here
    $stmh -> bindValue('username',$_POST['username'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmh -> bindValue('password',password_hash($_POST['userpassword'],PASSWORD_DEFAULT),PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmh -> execute();

    echo "登録しました<br>";
        }catch(PDOExcetion $e){
            echo "error ".$e->getMessage();
        }
    }

}

public function login(){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM userData WHERE username=:usrname";
    $stmh =$obj->prepare($sql);//the error occour here
    $stmh ->bindValue(':usrname',$_POST['username'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmh->execute();
    $row = $stmh->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if($row['username'] == false){
        echo"login fail";
        exit;
    }
    $hash = $row['password'];
    if (false === password_verify($_POST['userpassword'],$hash)){
        echo"login fail";
        exit;
    }
   }
}
```

**database.php**
i just create Database class, i want to use `$pdo` which is protected, so i create `getConnection()` function and return the `$pdo`. So what i think is i just create a object like `$obj=new Database();` `$obj->getConnection();` then i can access `$pdo` variable.But it doesn't work. The error occur at above "`member.php`". please help

```
<?php
class Database{

protected $pdo;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->db_connect();
}

private function db_connect()
{
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "abc";
    $password = "abc";
    $dbname = "mydb";
    try
    {
      $this->pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
      $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,false);
    }catch(PDOException $e)
        {
        die("error connection ".$e->getMessage());
        }
}
public function getConnection()
{   
    return $this->pdo;
}   
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: Well the variable is out of scope in the method. See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16959576/3933332

Comment: define variable inside the class

Comment: you should really be posting the full error message however both cases of `$obj` in your member class is undefined because of variable scope. `$obj` has been declared outside your class so for anything the class it doesn't exist

Comment: @Rizier123 looks like a dupe to me.

Comment: @Memor-x 
thanks, now i got this error what does it's means?
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$obj' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in C:\xampp\New folder\htdocs\todo\member.php on line 8

Answer (score 0):

Add `global $obj` in the function before any thing.